# How to print my hash value if it contains time stamp values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, printing

I have a hash in ruby i want to print it in proper manner using hash objects like hash.each_pair(). But its not working as it has some time stamp values.

```
    file1={:file_modify_date=>2015-01-08 12:34:34 +0530, :file_modify_date_civil=>Thu, 08    Jan 2015, :file_access_date=>2015-01-08 13:23:09 +0530, :file_access_date_civil=>Thu, 08 Jan 2015, :file_inode_change_date=>2015-01-08 12:34:34 +0530, :file_inode_change_date_civil=>Thu, 08 Jan 2015, :file_permissions=>"rw-r--r--", :file_type=>"JPEG", :mime_type=>"image/jpeg"}
file1.each_pair { |k, v| puts "Key: #{k}, Value: #{v}" }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Why aren't you using something like `pp` to pretty print them? Your code is not valid Ruby code.

Comment: Why is it not valid code? if i remove those time stamps it works fine

Comment: You said it yourself - the timestamps are incorrect. If you post correct code, it is easier for people to run your code and possibly help you out.

Comment: No i am not saying that time stamps are incorrect thats's correct but i want to print that hash in proper manner and its not printing as it has timestamp values.

Comment: The timestamps aren't correct ruby code. You can't paste your code into irb and run it. So it's not correct ruby. If I parse your timestamps using Time.parse, I can print the hash just fine using your method. So what's wrong?

Comment: What does "proper" mean for you?

Comment: Okay sorry my mistake. I am getting this hash by system generated values now i need to print this as hash key and values how can i do that? It will we really great if you can help me out.

Comment: Like This: "Key : Value"

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or is it printing something? What is it printing?

Comment: No i m getting an error :
Invalid octal digit
..., :file_modify_date=>2015-01-08 12:34:34 +0530, :file_modify...
...                               ^syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '}'
...file_modify_date=>2015-01-08 12:34:34 +0530, :file_modify_da...

Comment: @shilpi_agrawal: As you have already been told multiple times, your code is not valid Ruby code. It isn't even syntactically valid. `2014-01` is `2013`, `2013-08` is illegal, because integer literals starting with `0` are octal, but octal numbers can't contain the number `8`. The rest doesn't even make remotely sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about you format your `time_stamp` value to string

```
file1={:file_modify_date=> time1.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S +%z"), ....}
using strftime to format your time stamp
file1.each_pair { |k, v| puts "Key: #{k}, Value: #{v}" }
```

see also [Rails strftime](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/strftime)

Comment: Thank you @Nermin. But my hash is dynamically generated by system so i am not able to change it manually

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
file1={:file_modify_date=>'2015-01-08 12:34:34 +0530', :file_modify_date_civil=>'Thu, 08    Jan 2015', :file_access_date=>'2015-01-08 13:23:09 +0530', :file_access_date_civil=>'Thu, 08 Jan 2015', :file_inode_change_date=>'2015-01-08 12:34:34 +0530', :file_inode_change_date_civil=>'Thu, 08 Jan 2015', :file_permissions=>"rw-r--r--", :file_type=>"JPEG", :mime_type=>"image/jpeg"}

file1.each_pair { |k, v| puts "Key: #{k}, Value: #{v}" }
```